# Set powershell_transcript folder location

Tags: windows-10, powershell

My Documents folder keeps being spammed with datestamp folders which contain powershell_transcript files.
[image]

I did not enable/configure it, so it must be either a default setting or something set by organization administrators on a corporate level.
In any case, it seems rather dumb, because the folder is quickly overrun with logs that nobody reads.

How can I change the location of these folders, so that they all land in one place (e.g. `\Documents\PowerShell Transcripts`)?

I tried to find these settings in my Powershell profile files, but it seems there are none (`psEdit $PROFILE` and `$PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts` return a file not found result).

Kind regards

Comment: If it's part of the company policy just talk to your IT administration. Usually you'd use [`Start-Transscript`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-6). See the explanation for `-Path`.

Comment: @Seth - thanks. So, if I execute the StartTransscript command with proper path, will it preserve these settings 'permanently', or just for a given powershell session or until reboot or something?

Comment: No. But as mentioned the help and especially the description for the path parameter has the information about how to persist it and/or how your transcription path is being changed. [about_Profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6) has further information about profiles that you might want to check out.